# Bulleted list with NSTextList in NSTextView example?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextview

I would want to parse user input in a NSTextView, so that a line beginning with "- " would automatically start a bulleted list. What do I have to do to the NSTextView.textStorage to enable a bulleted list so that the next bullet automatically appears when you press Enter after each bullet line?

I've found a few examples but they all insert the bullets by hand, so I was wondering what's the point of specifying `let textList = NSTextList(markerFormat: "{box}", options: 0)` if you then have to manually insert the box-symbol yourself?

Currently I'm trying to implement this in a custom NSTextView with an overriden `shouldChangeTextInRange(affectedCharRange: NSRange, replacementString: String?)` So a simple example that would solve the simplest input case of "- " starting an automatic bulleted list, would be highly regarded.

Update:

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
override func shouldChangeTextInRange(affectedCharRange: NSRange, replacementString: String?) -> Bool {
   super.shouldChangeTextInRange(affectedCharRange, replacementString: replacementString)

   if string == "-" && replacementString == " " {
      let textList = NSTextList(markerFormat: "{disc}", options: 0)
      let textListParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
      textListParagraphStyle.textLists = [textList]
      let attributes = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: textListParagraphStyle]
      string = "\t\(textList.markerForItemNumber(0))\t"
      textStorage?.addAttributes(attributes, range: NSMakeRange(0, textStorage!.string.length))
      return false
   }
   else if affectedCharRange.location > 0 && replacementString == "\n\n" {
      textStorage?.insertAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "\t"), atIndex: affectedCharRange.location)
      return true
   }

   return true
}
```

I'm just trying to solve the simplest case of the user typing "- " as the first characters in the NSTextView. This is what happens with the code above:
[image: Output in custom NSTextView]

The bigger font in the beginning comes from the typingAttributes I have set. This gets automatically overriden later as you can see.

Returning false from the `else if` clause and inserting the \n directly there will prevent the NSTextView from automatically adding new bullets. After the first time I return `true` from there, new bullets are added automatically without calling this method???

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: None the wiser :o(

Answer (score -1):

Try to add bullets using Unicode character by replace `"- " with \u{2022}`

`textView.text = " \u{2022} This is a list item!`

Comment: I'm not trying to merely insert " • " in place of " -", which will of course look like the beginning of a list, but it doesn't create a NSTextList into the textView and thus it lacks all the editing functionality that a properly recognized list-object gives for free. If you press enter at the end of the first item, the next item beginning with a bullet won't be added by the textView. A correct answer will need to tell how to properly insert a NSTextList into the NSTextView.